# Treatment combinations in different blocks for a $2^6$ design with partial confounding

Tags: experiment-design, confounding, blocking, fractional-factorial

Let us consider a $2^6$ design in 8 blocks with ABCD, BCE and ADEF as independent effects are chosen to be confounded with blocks.

> Q.1 $\:$ Write down the treatment combinations in the principal block.
> Q.2 $\:$ Write down the treatment combinations in the remaining blocks.

I have found the defining contrasts-

$$ L_1 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 $$
$$ L_2 = x_2 + x_3 + x_5 $$
$$ L_3 = x_1 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 $$

Is there any easier way to solve questions 1 and 2? I can find them by checking the treatment combinations one by one using the defining contrasts. But I am searching for a way using which I can figure out them more quickly.

$\textbf{Edit}$:
Can you please tell me how can I find the treatment combinations only for the principal block?

One more question- Why ABCD, BCE and ADEF are called as "independent effects"?

Comment: You may want to take a look at factorial and fractional factorial designs. This will help you understand how to derive main effects from specific design generators.

Comment: PLease add the tag [tag:self-study] and read its wiki!

Comment: Actually, I know how to find the treatments combinations in the blocks. But that is a very time-consuming way. That's why I was trying for an easier way by which I can find the treatment effects more quickly.